# How to run installed whl format of a python project

Tags: python

I convert my python project to a `whl` format and transfer it to the server for run.
In the server first i install my `whl` via:

```
pip install myProject.whl
```

Now how to call a specific script of it (main.py)?
If I go to python bash, then i can call my specific script(main.py) via import :

```
(venv) lida@dn:/opt$ python
Python 3.8.10 (default, Sep 28 2021, 16:10:42) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>import myProject.main
```

But i don't want to use it. I want to call `main.py` out of the python bash like this:

```
(venv) lida@dn:/opt$python myProject.main
```

The above code is not correct. What is the correct answer?

Thanks all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to run it with [`python -m`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-m):

```sh
python -m myProject.main
```

> `-m <module-name>` 
> Search `sys.path` for the named module and execute its contents as the `__main__` module.

Source: https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-m